# JSReport External javascript with Json data required

Tags: jsreport

We have hosted jsreport node application on EBS. We created template and using css and javascripts from a static website(hosted internally). In the external javascript file we are using variables similar to what jsreport requires i.e. {{variablename}} which does not work. When we add the javascript inline in the template it works.

We know there should be some other way around to specify this but could not find it.

Comment: Could you share the code that works and the code that doesn't works. This would make your question a lot more user friendly and may get you better answer!

Answer (score 1):

This won't work. jsreport templating engines only compile and process the html output, not the referenced scripts.

However you can try this approach:

Put a placeholder in a template content where you want to put external script. Lets say we want to put inline jquery

```
<script>
    $$$myScript
</script>

<script>
    $(() => {
        alert('yes I have jquery inlined')
    })
</script>
```

Create jsreport [custom server script](http://jsreport.net/learn/scripts) which downloads your external script, in this case jquery, and replace the placeholder with its content

```
var getReq = require('request').get

function beforeRender(req, res, done) {
    getReq('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js', (err, res, body) => {
        req.template.content = req.template.content.replace('$$$myScript', body.toString())
        done()
    })
}
```

The script will run before the templating engines are executed therefore you can use templating engines tags inside it now.

**[playground live demo here](https://playground.jsreport.net/studio/workspace/S1RydU_h/7)**